# kafka topic with compact,delete does not remove old data

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka changelog topic which has a cleanup policy COMPACT_DELETE .

It has a retention.ms of 86520000 which is approximately 1 day.

However I've observed that partitions in this topic has data which is over a month old .

I would expect that since DELETE is also part of the cleanup policy there should be no messages beyond 1 day in any of the partitions in this topic .

The major problem here is that this topic is constantly growing and is never settling down which is causing disk issues in the kafka broker side.

I'd like to understand why retention.ms isnt kicking in for COMPACT_DELETE topics.

Comment: How large are the segment files on disk? What is the segment size set as?

Comment: segment.bytes is 10485760 and segment.ms is 600000

Comment: That's the config, not the answer to how large the actual Kafka data segment log files are on disk

Comment: the log files in disk are varied.. some are  ~6mb , 7mb , 10mb etc

Comment: ```7.5M 00000000000653938724.log
5.8M 00000000000654187433.log
8.8M 00000000000654375361.log
8.7M 00000000000654648751.log
9.4M 00000000000654946156.log
11M 00000000000655244327.log```

Comment: None of those files are larger than `segment.bytes`, so older data can be kept in them. I'm not sure about `segment.ms` since I've never set it

Comment: i think the active segment rolls over when either segment.bytes or segment.ms is reached . since my segment.ms is 10 minutes . ideally the segment is rolled over every 10 minutes if it doesnt reach 10mb and since there are so many such segments , the older segments should have been compacted which isnt happening

Comment: Did you dump those segments and find duplicate keys? There are other properties related to the "dirty ratio" of the segments and few other log cleaner settings... Maybe this post can help https://zendesk.engineering/an-investigation-into-kafka-log-compaction-5e520f4291f0

Answer (score 0):

this is explained by how the log cleaner operates. During compaction, it does not delete individual records based upon the retention.ms setting. It only deletes entire segments if all records in the segment are older than retention.ms. Using compact,delete with retention.bytes, the log manager thread will prune the topic such that the combined size of all log segments for each topic partition will be limited to retention.bytes thus limiting the amount of data retained for the compacted topic.The old records in question still exist since the segment that contains them also contains records that have not expired based upon retention.ms.